# How do I handle the "keydown.esc" event in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `<Parent>` component that renders the `<Modal>` component if a variable `showModal` is true.

The variable `showModal` is defined in the `setup(){}` function of the `<Parent>` component.

I want to close the modal when a user:

1. clicks the close button
2. when they hit the ESC button

**Parent component**

```
<template>
  <Modal v-if="isShownModal" @clickedModalClose="isShownModal=false" @keydown.esc="isShownModal=false">
  //removed some code for clarity purposes
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {Modal},
  setup(){

    const isShownModal = ref(false)
    ...
```

Notice the `@clickedModalClose="isShownModal=false"` and `@keydown.esc="isShownModal=false"`

**Modal component**

```
<template>

  <div class="modal is-active">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>  
    
    <div class="modal-content box">
      <slot name="header"></slot>
      <slot name="body"></slot>  
    </div>
  
    <!-- Listen to a custom event @clicked-modal-close (v-on) --> 
    <button @click="$emit('clickedModalClose')" class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
  </div>
  
</template>
```

To close the modal I'm emitting an event when a close button is clicked within the child component and listening for that event `@clickedModalClose` and as expected that closes the modal correctly

Nonetheless, when I hit the ESC button nothing happens even though I have the event handler declared on the Modal component: `<Modal v-if="isShownModal" @clickedModalClose="isShownModal=false" @keydown.esc="isShownModal=false">`

I also tried attaching the `@keydown.esc="closeTheModal()"` to a DIV and `template` tag within the `<Modal>` and thenemitted the `clickedModalClose` event programatically within the `closeTheModal()` function , but to no avail

Could someone, please, shed some light to this problem :/

**UPDATE**

The correct answer is given by @blackgreen

After the  component is rendered in order to handle the ESC event that event has to be attached to a DOM element within the  component.

What I did is I simply used template references on the Modal closing button to have it available in the `onMounted(){}` hook and called the `focus()` method on it

**Parent component**

```
<Modal @keydown.esc="isShownModal=false">
```

**Child component**

```
<template>
<button ref="closingButton" class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</template>
```

and in the JS part:

```
<script>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
export default {
  setup(props, context){
    
    const closingButton = ref(null)
    onMounted(()=>{
      closingButton.value.focus()
    })

    return {closingButton}

  }
}
```

Comment: I can't find the `@keydown` statement in the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#system-modifier-keys), only `@keyup.esc`. But I guess it will not solve the case. I would bind the event handler to the `window`and not to the `<Modal />` component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binding `@keydown.esc` is correct ([demonstrative fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9jyxe3p/)).

But for the event to be actually fired, the element on which the listener is declared must be on focus.

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6yx25t1/) example, the `mounted` hook sets the focus on a `<div>` element with `tabindex=0` (a trick so that it can have focus). If you press Esc while that div is focused, you'll see the counter incrementing as well.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense... The event has to be attached to a DOM element to bubble... I'll check the solution later today. Cheers!!!